# httpRuntime targetFramework and dlls that depend on higher version of the .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My web.config file of an asp.net mvc 5 application has the `httpRuntime` `targetFramework="4.5"` and `compile` `targetFramework="4.5.1"`. I recently started to use dapper which required me to re-target the app to `4.5.1`. Re-targetting the app did not change the `httpRuntime targetFramework`.

Do I need to set the `httpRuntime targetFramework` to `4.5.1` as well in the web.config file or should I leave it the way it is? The test and production systems run .Net framework `4.5.2`.

Thanks

Update: I found an interesting article: https://dennisgorelik.livejournal.com/132999.html. and also this one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/.

Comment: If the test and production systems run .Net framework 4.5.2, you should also use that for local development.

Comment: I actually do run 4.5.2 and I haven't seen any issues. The doc on the httpRutime targetFramework is not very helpful.

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.targetframework(v=vs.110).aspx) don't describe what happens if the `httpRuntime targetFramework` is missing:

Comment: According to the second link:`If the targetFramework attribute is not present, we assume a default value of "4.0"`

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a newer framework than 4.5. There are functional upgrades with newer versions but all of them install into the same target folder (the one of .NET 4.5) and overwrite existing files.
This applies to 4.6.x or 4.7.x as well. This is different from previous framework versions where they could (or must) coexist.

In fact you can run an application with a newer framework (>= 4.5) on a web server with an older one using this hack. Of course, only if you did not used framework classes of the newer framework. Otherwise you get an ugly exception of the class loader. (BTDT)

To avoid pitfalls like that I recommend not to have inconsistent versions in the web.config file unless you have good reasons to do so.